# How to pars inner XML Tags with SAX

Tags: java, sax

I am trying to read data from an XML file by using SAX. But i cant figure out how to handle the inner `<Path>` Tag...

How to do pars the inner path element?

This is my XML file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings>
    <files>
        <backup isActive="true">
            <Path>way/to/backup</Path>
        </backup>
        <config>
            <Path>way/to/config</Path>
        </config>
        <data>
            <Path>way/to/data</Path>
        </data>
    </files>
</settings>
```

Here the neccessary java code snippets.

```java
   @Override
   public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
      if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("backup")) {
         Boolean isActive = Boolean.valueOf(attributes.getValue("isActive"));
         System.out.println("isActive : " + isActive);
         Settings.Backup.setEnabled(isActive);
         hasBackup = true;
      } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("config")) {
         hasConfig= true;
      } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("data")) {
         hasData = true;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

      if (hasBackup) {
         System.out.println("Backup: "
                 + new String(ch, start, length));
         hasBackup = false;
      } else if (hasConfig) {
         System.out.println("Config: " + new String(ch, start, length));
         hasConfig = false;
      } else if (hasData) {
         System.out.println("Data: " + new String(ch, start, length));
         hasData = false;
      }
   }
```

I dont feel like adding the following code is the right approach at all ...

```java
else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("path")) {
         System.out.println("path");
         ...
      }
```

I think i have to trigger new qName somehow ... but i dont know how. Than i would just check for backup and than inside the backup i would than run an

```java
if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("backup")) {
    Boolean isActive = Boolean.valueOf(attributes.getValue("isActive"));
    System.out.println("isActive : " + isActive);
    Settings.Backup.setEnabled(isActive);
    hasBackup = true;
    trigger next qName?
    if(qname.equalsIgnorCase("path") {
        Settings.Backup.setPath(path)
    }
}
```

Also i am asking myself if i should allready handle Attributes inside the startElement or at the characters method.

Comment: "Should i handle it inside the `startElement()` already?" Yes. "Or in the `characters()` method?" No, it won't come through there. Have you tried either of these?

Comment: actually i tried to implement startElement() but i couldnt get it to work ... ....

Comment: "I couldn't get it to work" is not a problem description.

Comment: I think i have to trigger new qName somehow ... but i dont know how. Than i would just check for backup and than inside the backup i would than get a new Qname and check for path inside the if case for backup?... Is it possible to get the next qName somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On style:

- Arrays

  ```
    char ch[] = C/C++ compatible style
    char[] ch = brackets with rest of type, Java
  ```
- Variable and method names are camel case with a starting small letter.
- Indentation: 4 spaces

  Probably a measure to have less nested blocks.
- Primitive types boolean, int, double better than Object wrappers Boolean, Integer, Double.

Some issues: `characters can be called more than once, deliver just a partial text piece. The parsing with startElement events are tiresome

Now to collect characters:

```
private String path = null;

@Override
public void characters(char[] chs, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (path != null) {
        path += new String(chs, start, length));
        System.out.printf("Path characters from %d, length %d: %s%n", start, length path);
    }
}
```

You'll need endElement too:

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("Start of " + qName);
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("path")) {
        path = "";
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("backup")) {
        boolean isActive = Boolean.valueOf(attributes.getValue("isActive"));
        System.out.println("isActive : " + isActive);
        settings.backup.setEnabled(isActive);
        hasBackup = true;
        hasConfig= false;
        hasData = false;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("config")) {
        hasBackup = false;
        hasConfig= true;
        hasData = false;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("data")) {
        hasBackup = false;
        hasConfig= false;
        hasData = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    System.out.println("End of " + qName);
    switch (qName) {
    case "backup": -> {
            System.out.println("backup:" + path);
            path = null;
        }
    case "config": -> {
            System.out.println("config:" + path);
            path = null;
        }
    case "data": -> {
            System.out.println("data:" + path);
            path = null;
        }
    case "path": -> System.out.println("Path results in: " + path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there thx allready for trying to help :D. I tried your way of implementing it exactly as you described it. But the output seems a bit weird -> (backup:
        
config:
        
data:
        
config:
        
data:
        
data:
        ) and path is never the acctual string but empty or null? hmm

Comment: i mean output for backup should be for example -> (backup: way/to/backup) or am i wrong xD thats at least what i expected :D

Comment: makes sense now :D. The only issue i have now that it seams to have a lot duplication output -> (backup:
            way/to/backup
        
config:
            way/to/backup
        
data:
            way/to/backup
        
config:
            way/to/backup
            way/to/config
data:
            way/to/backup
            way/to/config
data:
            way/to/backup
            way/to/config
            way/to/data
) expected ->backup:
            way/to/backup
config:
            way/to/config
data:
            way/to/data

Comment: output -> (backup:way/to/backup
        
config:way/to/backup
        
data:way/to/backup
        
config:way/to/config
        
data:way/to/config
        
data:way/to/data) hmm i feel like handling inner tags in SAX is a pain xD

Comment: It is the most primitive form, event driven on start and end tag, characters and so on. Good to learn debugging. Normally one uses XPath or something like Java XML binding (Jakarta now)

Comment: yeha but the current output of your solution is wrong xD as i see it ? for example the "data:way/to/config" part

Comment: Added with output to see what happens.